# How to prove arcsine law for amount of time Brownian motion is positive in $[0,t]$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Ross's *Introduction to Stochastic Processes* states, but does not prove this result:

> For Brownian motion, let $A(t)$ denote the amount of time in $[0,t]$ the process is positive. Then, for $0<x<1$, $$\mathbb P(A(t)/t\leqslant x) = \frac2\pi \arcsin \sqrt x. $$

How can this be proven?

Comment: Take e.g. a look at Application 8.7 in *Brownian motion - An introduction to stochastic processes* by Schilling & Partzsch. Pretty sure that there are other books which contain the proof as well...

Comment: @saz Thanks for the reference.